# PHP PDO check if data exists not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am working on my blog and I can't seem to figure this out. The if `($result->fetchColumn())` should be working. It does give the error but when data(row) exists it does not show anything. What is wrong?

```
    <?php
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = $id";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->fetchColumn() > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<div class="post-preview">
                    <a>
                        <h2 class="post-title">
                            '.$row["title"].'
                        </h2>
                        <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                            '.$row["content"].'
                        </h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta"><a href="#">'.$row["creator"].'</a> | '.$row["date"].'</p>
                </div>
                <hr>';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<center><h1>Post does not exist.</h1></center>";
            header("Refresh: 2; url=index.php");
        }
    ?>
```

Whenever I remove the line `if ($result->fetchColumn() > 0) {` it works fine. But I need to check if the $id exists in the database. If it does, it should show the data, if not it should show the error and link back to index.php.

Comment: In your mind, what is `if ($result->fetchColumn() > 0) ` supposed to do? Determine whether you have rows so you can proceed with fetching them? Also, have you consulted PHP manual to see what `fetchColumn` does and where it's supposed to be used?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection! Please use [PDO prepared statements to run this query](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could be much simpler

Just populate your $row variable and see whether it contains anything or not.

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = ?");
$stmt->execute([$_GET["id"]]); // essential to protect from SQL injection!
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
if ($row) {
        echo '<div class="post-preview">
                <a>
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        '.$row["title"].'
                    </h2>
                    <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                        '.$row["content"].'
                    </h3>
                </a>
                <p class="post-meta"><a href="#">'.$row["creator"].'</a> | '.$row["date"].'</p>
            </div>
            <hr>';
    }
    else {
        echo "<center><h1>Post does not exist.</h1></center>";
        header("Refresh: 2; url=index.php");
    }
```